# How to set up sidecar without giving Apple your account password?

Tags: icloud, password, sidecar

Please demonstrate how to set up an iPad using sidecar to both a MacBook Pro and an iMac without giving Apple access to your local computer's account password (which can be used to decrypt all of your files offline if someone is physically seated at your powered-off computer).

Rules:

1. Must have two-factor authentication enabled (because I have an Apple developer account, fml).
2. All devices must have only one user account.
3. Switching the iPad between the MacBook Pro and iMac must not require resetting your passwords.
4. You must not give Apple your correct password in this box*:
   [image]
5. If you give Apple a fake or alternate password (and then switch the correct password (for #4)) then you must show that sidecar consistently works **after** the new correct password (which Apple does not have) is in effect.

---

* Why not just give Apple your password?

Apple claims in the screen before the above "your password cannot be read by Apple". This is a very weak claim. And Apple (or its agent or compelling party) might still guess and verify your password without technically "reading" it. This is how a significant number of password compromises happen in the wild today.

Comment: Hey - the only weak claim I see here is the idea that your local account password leaves your device. Feel free to hit us up in [chat] if we can help edit / clarify. I did post an answer that I hope helps and can shape a better answer if I missed the mark.

Comment: You've previously posted here with a link to a blog claiming that Apple takes your admin password when you set up TFA. In which case, as you already have TFA enabled, then the cat/horse is out of the bag/stable.

Comment: in case you disagree with my removal of your monetary bounty note, [Chat] or [meta] should be a good place to discuss that.

Comment: Regarding 2FA. Apple has fixed their product and it is no longer necessary for you to leak Apple your password to set up 2FA.

Comment: @bmike There is no claim that the local account password leaves the device. And so that is not a "weak" claim. Specifically, the hashed version of your local account password is what is leaving your device. And even that is unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for removing the bounty if I'm not allowed to give out money here. And thank you for checking my other questions. You can also see that I have fixed actual vulns with Apple and they have publicly credited me (link below). But I ask please that any downvotes here please be based actually on this question. Maybe privacy & security are not popular now, but I hope these can be on-topic for discussion on this site.

Comment: I support William here. Votes shouldn’t be about disagreeing with a point or because something is going to be very hard to answer. This is +1 in my book and worth discussing technically. I can’t see how [this is either “ egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post” or entirely unuseful to get answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Even if people post wrong answers, contravening answers or kind and critical comments can educate everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you equate giving apple your password to typing the admin credentials, then you can’t do this without a privilege escalation / security vulnerability. Those usually pay $25,000 to $250,000 so if anyone has one - get your money from apple before posting here how to hack your mac.

- https://developer.apple.com/security-bounty/payouts/

If you just need us to confirm you aren’t sending your password off device in the prompt you showed, you are set. Use the admin password and understand that Apple doesn’t send your password off the device, it entangles a local key with a downloaded public key and then stores the results in your keychain.

Apple already has your iCloud password so it doesn’t need to record / steal / transmit your local password for sidecar to work. I understand you would love to have someone show you the way, but as I read it, your intentions are good but your threat model analysis is faulty here.

Comment: I’ll try to set up sidecar and show you the secret that syncs via iCloud to establish that both devices are eligible to secure the highly confidential information you are about to broadcast from your Mac to the iPad. Apple engineering has thought deeply about security and privacy here so that when you set this up, no one else other than you (shown by your local / iCloud passwords) can see the data from mac to iPad and back.

Comment: I have successfully reported vulnerabilities to Apple. Lest anybody think I'm a whack job, they have publicly credited me here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201536

Comment: I understand that my Apple password is something that Apple and I share. My local password is different and I do not share that with Apple. My local password encrypts the hard disk and gives root access on my machine if I only have one user on the machine. My threat model is my local password, or a hash of it, should not be shared to Apple.

Comment: When you describe "and then stores the results in your keychain" that must necessarily be in Apple's control. Therefore (local_key, public_key) is given to Apple. That means Apple could guess and verify the local_key. Therefore threat model violated.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken no such thoughts crossed my mind. I’m super appreciative of security researchers and people skeptical of any claim. Fair enough if you either have proof the password is hashed and leaves or just want to be sure it isn’t before typing it. I think we’re all in agreement the password doesn’t have to be compromised to set this up, but whether the design is thusly done.

Comment: Cool. I had reached out to Apple and they failed to provide details on how this (very important) system is implemented. So I must assume it is implemented in the naive way that meets the few exacts claims they've made if I trust Apple's word (which I do). -- One telling feature is that your iPad asks "what is your iMac password?" and if you type it wrong then the iPad knows, without the iMac being online.